# Trouble connecting to company VPN through Windows 10

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-10

I have been trying to connect to my company's VPN for days in vain now. I haven't used a VPN on my Windows 10 laptop before. I added the new VPN connection to Settings - Network & Internet - VPN: provided the server name, VPN type (L2TP/IPSec with pre-shared key), pre-shared key, type of sign-in info (username and password), and the username and password I was given. When trying to connect, I get the following error message which I don't understand since all my colleagues are using the same VPN without trouble:

```
The network connection between your computer and the VPN server could not be established because the remote server is not responding. This could be because one of the network devices (e.g. firewalls, NAT, routers, etc) between your computer and the remote server is not configured to allow VPN connections. Please contact your Administrator or your service provider to determine which device may be causing the problem.
```

The steps I have tried so far:

1. Pinging both the IP address of the VPN server and the server name : both worked fine.
2. Running `netsh interface show interface` sshows only two interfaces: Ethernet and WiFi, i.e. the VPN is missing.
3. Running `netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces` shows six rows: WiFi, Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1, Bluetooth Network Connection 4, Ethernet, Local Area Connection* 1, Local Area Connection* 3, i.e. again, no trace of a VPN.
4. I added the `AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule` entry to the registry with a value set to 2.
5. I made sure that Microsoft CHAP v2 protocol is enabled.
6. I made sure that LCP extensions are also enabled.
7. I changed IPSec Policy Agent startup type from Manual to Automatic.
8. I disabled the ipv6 protocol for the VPN in the Windows Control Panel.
9. I removed and reinstalled WAN Miniport (IP), WAN Miniport(IPv6) and WAN Miniport (PPTP).
10. In the Local Security Policy, I changed LAN Manager authentication level to `Send LM & NTLM - use NTMLv2 session security if negotiated`.
11. In the Local Security Policy, Minimum session security for NTML SSP based (including secure RPC) clients, I unchecked the `Require 128-bit encryption`.
12. I disabled `Xbox Live Networking Services`.
13. I tried temporarily disabling all three firewalls: Public Network, Private Network, Domain Network.

**Edit:** Retried connecting to the VPN both from a public and from a private network.

Comment: What did your company IT department tell you to do when you called them (as you should have already done)?

Comment: Well, they pretty much said they have no clue... they are mostly/exclusively Mac users and weren't able to provide me with much beyond some online tutorials on how to set up VPN with Win10 that I have also found on Google by myself.

Comment: Take your laptop to a coffee shop and try to connect via the public WiFi. If it works, the problem is with your home ISP or home networking equipment.

Comment: Tried the process both from my home WiFi, home Ethernet, and now a public WiFi.

Comment: Were they able to provide instructions for Mac? Perhaps those can carry over to PC in some respects.